# What Keys Are Represented by the &H Hex Codes?

Tags: vb.net, programming-languages, hex

**EDIT:** I found an article that lists exactly what I needed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks for your help!

*Original:*

I'm wondering what keyboard keys are represented by the `&H` hex codes?

For example, I've found that `&H1` is the ALT key, `&H2` is the CONTROL key, and `&H3` is both the ALT and CONTROL keys together. `&H10` is the Shift key, it appears. I'm asking because I need to find out for a program I'm designing that needs to register a hotkey. The user has the option to hide it, and I want to make sure that they can show it again by pressing a hotkey, but I need to figure out what the hex keys are to use the code that I found.

Here's part of the code I found:

```
Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1 'Alt key
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
                    ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, _
                    ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
                    ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)
            Case "100"
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+D key combination")
            Case "200"
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+C key combination")
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

And this registers the hotkeys when the form loads:

```
RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, &H3, Keys.D)
RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 200, Keys.Alt, Keys.C)
```

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/c1a24688-d844-4adc-9d85-416a7158c6ba/) is the thread I was looking at on the MSDN forums -- I copied the code from the featured answer.

I've done a thorough Google search and I've searched here on StackOverflow, and I can't find anything.

Is there maybe a list of the hex codes somewhere, or instructions or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that MSDN thread you've linked there is a link to [Virtual Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx).
In addition, check the [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28VS.90%29.aspx) enumeration.

Notice that the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method takes the following arguments: hWnd, id, fsModifiers and vk. VK is where you place the VirtualKey code. Regarding fsModifiers:

> The keys that must be pressed in
>   combination with the key specified by
>   the uVirtKey parameter in order to
>   generate the WM_HOTKEY message. The
>   fsModifiers parameter can be a
>   combination of the following values:
>   MOD_ALT (0x0001), MOD_CONTROL
>   (0x0002), MOD_NOREPEAT (0x4000),
>   MOD_SHIFT (0x0004), MOD_WIN (0x0008).

Comment: A.

Thanks for answering! The problem is that the Virtual Key Codes are different than the hex codes I've seen -- do I need to convert them?

For example, in the VKC chart, it says that the ALT key is 12, but the hex code is &H1, so I don't really get it. Sorry!

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain about the modifiers. Check the RegisterHotKey link.

Comment: A. I've figured it out! Thanks a lot!